Set surrounding background of an SVG document (not the SVG background)
I am trying to make an SVG "slide deck" using JessyInk. This works very well for my needs except for 1 issue. In a browser window not the same size as was used for previewing during creation, JessyInk fits the SVG as best it can, centered within the window, leaving white space either above/below or left/right of the SVG.
I want those surrounding areas black, not white.
I have tried various combinations of style elements and attributes within the SVG, but those only affect within the SVG. The surrounding white space remains.
For example, I added body { background: black; } by various means, including as a  element and as a style attribute. This affected the SVG background, not the surrounding white, outside the SVG.
Then I tried embedding the SVG inside another, but then JessyInk does not work. Same if I embed the SVG inside an HTML document. In this surrounding HTML document, I used  elements to set the background black and the SVG background white. I ended up with a completely black document.
I also tried using percentages in the height, width and viewBox attributes. doing this just makes the matter worse.
I have tried other tools besides JessyInk, but they have the same problem.
Is there a way to do what I want?

I've never heard of "JessyInk" but it looks like it's for something for Inkscape? I'm guessing you might be able to set the artboard color to the color that you want it to be? Or, if it's a web-based renderer, you might be able to use CSS to style the background color but you'll need to figure out what element to select. It'd be something like body { background: black; }

JessyInk is a set of JavaScript functions plus an extension for Inkscape (the extension inserts some definiions and the JavaScript into the SVG file). Other than relying on named layers as created by Inkscape, the functionality could be replicated as a standalone tool.

With that information, I'd suggest the place to edit to remove the standard background fill, would be the Jessylink scripting. (Which I'm also unfamiliar with)
